# Get Current Year in a View Using the Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm coming from a Rails background and trying to learn the Phoenix Framework. In Rails I used to do this in my footer so that the year is always up to date:

```
<%= Date.now.year %>
```

What is the Phoenix/Elixir equivalent? How can I show the current year in the view?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Elixir 1.3.0 (which has just been released) has a very simple date library. For example, in order to get the current year, you could do something like:

> DateTime.utc_now |> Map.fetch!(:year)

@Dogbert below has also suggested a much easier way than the above:

> DateTime.utc_now.year

Which returns

> 2016

Another solution (if you don't want to use Elixir 1.3.0) is to use an external library such as [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex)

Where you could do something very similar:

> Date.today |> Map.fetch!(:year)

Which will again return

> 2016

Comment: You can also just do `DateTime.utc_now.year`.

Comment: @Dogbert thanks for that - must have had a brainfade! I have updated the answer.

Comment: I think @MichaelKaravaev and @Dogbert's answers are the most succinct.  You can also follow the same pattern with the hugely helpful Timex library: `Timex.today.year`

Comment: Or similar as mentioned before `Date.utc_today.year`